# How might I implement a complex ListItem for SWT/JFace?

Tags: user-interface, swt, jface

The more modern UI frameworks offer some kind of support for complex ListItems. For example, a picture and 3 lines of text.

How can I do this in an eclipse RCP application? Are there any open source frameworks for this?

Comment: Did you checked Nebula http://www.eclipse.org/nebula/ project

Comment: @ChandrayyaGK - yes. I thought the Gallery might help but it seems to just handle images.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `TableViewer` and use an `OwnerDrawLabelProvider`. This label provider gives you complete control over what is drawn in the table rows. The disadvantage is that you do have to draw the rows yourself using `GC` based operations (not too hard for images and text).

Comment: Thanks. How feasible is it to add databinding to the list items to ensure the view always reflects the model?

Comment: @paul I haven't tried that but you probably just need a label provider that duplicates some of the code from `ObservableMapLabelProvider` (which is not large).